# vb6 textbox show false message sdafjklasdf

Tags: vb6

textbox show "false" when I click datalist .
please help me . 
stuck here  .
`Private Sub DataList1_Click()
Txtnama.Text = DataList1.ListField = "nama"
End Sub`

please help me guys  .

Comment: Will be better if explain us what You want and what You done for it.

Comment: I have database on access example In table customer i have two fields ID n NAME.. i have ID 101 with NAME : JOHN.. On datalist I use ID for listfields..I want when I choose 101 then show name JOHN on text box.. Please help me.. Sorry about my English

Answer (score 2):

You can't cascade an assignment statement.  Your statement is performing a comparison: `Datalist1.ListField = "nama"`, then assigning the results of that comparison (True or False) to the textbox.

Perhaps you want to be assigning the same value to the textbox and list field?  If so, then you should use this:

```
txtnama.Text = "nama"
DataList1.ListField = "nama"
```

If that's not what you are trying to do, then you need to provide a better, more complete explanation of your requirements.

Comment: I have database on access example In table customer i have two fields ID n NAME.. i have ID 101 with NAME : JOHN.. On datalist I use ID for listfields..I want when I choose 101 then show name JOHN on text box.. Please help me.. Sorry about my English

Comment: You'll need to either read both fields when you're loading the datalist then reference the name that matches the id, or if you're only loading the id into the datalist, then after selecting a list item, you'll need to go back and read the database for the name that matches the id.  Either way, you need to show more code than what you have shown in order to get better recommendations and help.  You need to provide enough code for someone to be able to reproduce your error/problem - you have not done so.